# PHP getters and setters with array

Tags: php, arrays, getter-setter

If i use magic __set to set a value to private var how could i set a var as an array ?

Im thinking of something like this, pretend i have a  class with __get __set

```
$myclass->names = 'Name'; // Works
$myclass->names = array('n1'=>'Name1', 'n2' => 'Name2'); // works as well

//this does not work
$myclass->names['n1'] = 'Name1';
$myclass->names['n2'] = 'Name2';
```

Its the 2 last examples i want to get to work. Have tested various ways but cant figure it out.

Comment: Do you get an error or warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work. `$class->arr['key']` will execute the getter. So basically, what your code will look like is:

```
array('key' => 'value')['key'] = 'new value';
```

Which, obviously, does nothing. If you want that to work, you will have to declare the `names` as a public property.

Comment: While you're right about "it won't work", you're explanation of why is plain wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You obviously don't output notices, otherwise you'd have gotten the error

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Foo::$bar has no
>   effect

What you're trying to do is simply not possible. There is exactly one way to make arrays received through `__get` writable, but that is most likely not what you want.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    protected $bar = array();

    public function &__get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        return $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo $foo->bar[0]; // output "a"
$foo->bar[0] = 'z'; // fires warning
echo $foo->bar[0]; // output "z"

// all fine, but here's the catch:
$t =& $foo->bar;
$t = array('y');
echo $foo->bar[0]; // output "y"
```

Now that you've seen how returning values by reference can be a problem, you may be interested in [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php). Something like

```
<?php

class Foo {
    protected $bar = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return new ArrayObject(&$this->$name);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        return $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = array('a', 'b', 'c');
echo $foo->bar[0]; // output "a"
$foo->bar[0] = 'z'; // fires warning
echo $foo->bar[0]; // output "z"

// all fine, and no catch
$t =& $foo->bar;
$t = array('y');
echo $foo->bar[0]; // still outputs "z"
```

Comment: Yes i got some error in output but since i worked with this last time on friday i had forgotten about it. Im instead using now public var which works as supposed

Answer (score 2):

This expression will invoke the getter:

```
 $myclass->names['n1'] = 'Name1';
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 needs to be get
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                assignment later
```

The only way to make that work is a fugly workaround. By letting the getter return an **reference** to the know array the following assignment could work.

```
 function & __get($name) {

     if (is_array($this->$name)) {
          return & $this->$name;
     }
     else ...
 }
```

So it's really only advisable if it *significantly* simplifies your API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
class Foo
{
    private $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = new ArrayObject(array());
    }

    public function __get($item)
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $item)) {
            return $this->$item;
        }
    }

    public function __set($item, $value)
    {
        if(property_exists($this, $item)) {
            $this->{$item} = $value;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->bar['color'] = 'green';
foreach($obj->bar as $attribute => $value) {
    echo '<p>' . $attribute . ' : ' . $value . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
}
// output => color : green
```

Comment: The class declares `bar` privately, yet the calling code access' it as if it was public. This will not work.

Comment: Of course this will work because of public magic getter/setter methods. In fact, when you say `echo $obj->bar;` the __get method with be called with `'bar'` parameter sent to it and when you say `$obj->bar = 5;` the setter is called with `'bar`' and `5` parameters. Read more about magic methods.

Comment: I don't remember writing that comment... but I clearly didn't read your code properly. You are, of course, correct.